# What's in a na᠎me?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Due to a certain recent renaming, what change has occurred?

| Before (out of order) | After (in order) |
| --- | --- |
| Confirmed (6) | Compound having the fifth element [1,4] |
| Disinterested (5) | Daydreams [5] |
| Grove (5) | Refuses [1,4,6] |
| Has the ____ for (4) | Subatomic particle [1,4] |
| Marry (3) | Oppose [6] |
| Opposite (7) | Lift [1] |
| Relaxes (5) | More passionate, in a way [6] |
| Sheen, in England (6) | Expansive [1] |
| Subatomic particle (7) | Imitations [2] |
| Thick (5) | Supply [2,6] |

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lovely word puzzle :) This is clearly inspired by the recent news story about:

> the country **Turkey** renaming itself officially as [**Türkiye**](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-61671913) - a name change that effectively (umlaut aside) involves **swapping the last two letters and inserting an 'I' just before them**.

As what we need to do is:

> 1. Identify the words defined in the left-hand column, their lengths indicated by the number in brackets.
>  2. Pair these up with words in the right-hand column that can be formed by applying **a similar transformation**.
>  3. Index into these new words at the positions indicated in square brackets to pull out an answer phrase.

Resolving the left-hand column then:

> Confirmed (6) **PROVED**
>  Disinterested (5) **BORED**
>  Grove (5) **COPSE**
>  Has the ____ for (4) **HOTS**
>  Marry (3) **WED**
>  Opposite (7) **REVERSE**
>  Relaxes (5) **RESTS**
>  Sheen, in England (6) **LUSTRE**
>  Subatomic particle (7) **NEUTRON**
>  Thick (5) **DENSE**

The right-hand column:

> Compound having the fifth element [1,4] BORED → **[B]OR[I]DE**
>  Daydreams [5] REVERSE → **REVE[R]IES**
>  Refuses [1,4,6] DENSE → **[D]EN[I]E[S]**
>  Subatomic particle [1,4] NEUTRON → **[N]EU[T]RINO**
>  Oppose [6] RESTS → **RESIS[T]**
>  Lift [1] HOTS → **[H]OIST**
>  More passionate, in a way [6] LUSTRE → **LUSTI[E]R**
>  Expansive [1] WED → **[W]IDE**
>  Imitations [2] COPSE → **C[O]PIES**
>  Supply [2,6] PROVED → **P[R]OVI[D]E**

Which allows us to extract the phrase:

> **BIRD ISN'T THE WORD**! A reference to both the [famous song lyric](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/bird-is-the-word/) that then entered popular culture and the fact the country Türkiye no longer shares its name with the turkey bird!

A note on my 'in':

> Spotting that 'Subatomic particle' appeared on both sides (and the one on the left had 7 letters) led immediately in my mind to some kind of letter-based transformation to alter NEUTRON into the fairly similar NEUTRINO. I next spotted COPSE and COPIES, realised the transformation was the same, and then recalled the 'recent renaming' of Turkey. Applying the same method to the other entries kept resulting in further matches - I was clearly on the right track and so followed it through to completion...